# Windows Anytime Upgrade unsuccessful

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade

I tried to upgrade my Windows 7 Home Premium to Professional but the upgrade failed and here's the error in the upgrade.log file:
DoTransmogrify failed due to error 0x80070002

I did a quick search and afterwards disabled UAC as well as my Anti Virus. UAC asked me to restart the computer so I did. However, to my surprise, when the computer was booting, the upgrade process continued and finished successfully (I'm using Professional now). So I want to know why did this happen? Originally it said unsuccessful then exited yet when I restarted the computer everything continued just fine. Will I run into any problem in the future?

Comment: may be ur antivirus software stopped upgrading the system files or access for the setup

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If the upgrade was successful what does it matter if it failed because of the configuration of your system?

Comment: @Ramhound he's asking if it's possible that since it had an error and then it worked, maybe Windows didn't do a full upgrade of everything (hence the last sentence :D)

Answer (score 0):

When I googled the error code I found this link:

[You receive a "0x80070002" or "0x80070003" error code after you download an update from Windows Update, from Microsoft Update, or from Windows Server Update Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910336)

You can click the *Fix the problem automatically* link to have Microsoft try and fix it.